# Why data is not showing getting from firebase user in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting user data after signin from firebase. I am also printing it on console and it is showing that the data is here. But when I am trying to show it, it is not showing. There is no error also. I checked the element from the browser developer tools and see there the field is empty. I want to show **displayName, email, emailVerified**.

Here is the image of console that is showing I am getting data:

[image]

**My code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const Home = () => {
  // get user information
  let displayName, email, emailVerified;

  const auth = getAuth();
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
      displayName = user.displayName;
      email = user.email;
      emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      // User is signed out
      // ...
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card w-75 mx-auto bg-warning mt-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">Name: {displayName}</h5>
          <h5 className="card-title">Email: {email}</h5>
          <h5 className="card-title">Verified: {emailVerified}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Why the data is not showing? How can I show that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables will not work that way - you need to use state in your component, see:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

To elaborate - in functional components, the context of the function is essentially the render. Defining them at the top of the scope there will be disconnected from where they are set in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback - the component will have already been rendered with empty values at the point that the callback is called and won't re-render.

React state is what is used to handle this - and will tirgger a render when they change.

This can be done something like:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  if (user) {
    setUser(user);
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});

return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="card w-75 mx-auto bg-warning mt-3">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">Name: {user?.displayName}</h5>
        <h5 className="card-title">Email: {user?.email}</h5>
        <h5 className="card-title">Verified: {user?.emailVerified}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```